# Powerschool Python API

Tags: python-2.7, powerschool

I cannot find a good way in Python that connects to powerschool and gives me my current gpa. Can someone please help me. As much as possible, I'm trying not to use external api's. This is my Powerschool website: https://ps.d102.org/public/

Answer (score 1):

Through quick google searching, I found two options. Neither work with the current version of PowerSchool, but your school doesn't appear to be on the most recent version. Give these a try:

https://github.com/powerapi/powerapi-python

https://github.com/ouiliame/ps.py

Comment: Are there any python 3 alternatives? Or a way to convert the libraries